# How to make a query from table that counts how many days is a SKU without stock

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I have a MySQL database with a table called **stock_log** with this data:

| sku | date | quantity stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2021-11-18 | 0 |
| 123 | 2021-11-18 | 0 |
| 146 | 2021-11-18 | 0 |
| 111 | 2021-11-19 | 5 |
| 123 | 2021-11-19 | 4 |
| 146 | 2021-11-19 | 0 |
| 111 | 2021-11-20 | 3 |
| 123 | 2021-11-20 | 4 |
| 146 | 2021-11-20 | 0 |
| 111 | 2021-11-21 | 3 |
| 123 | 2021-11-21 | 0 |
| 146 | 2021-11-21 | 0 |
| 111 | 2021-11-22 | 2 |
| 123 | 2021-11-22 | 0 |
| 146 | 2021-11-22 | 0 |
| 111 | 2021-11-23 | 0 |
| 123 | 2021-11-23 | 0 |
| 146 | 2021-11-23 | 2 |

So, I need to make a query that counts how many days a SKU is without stock to today (2021-11-23), only if today is without stock, grouped by SKU. Also it must count the days without stock from the last date when it has no stock (because a SKU could have stock 3 consecutive days, then again 0, then again it has stock and then again 0).

So the query should shows:

| sku | days without stock |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 0 |
| 123 | 2 |

**NOTES:**

- **SKU 111:** 0 days without stock from today. 123
- **SKU 123:** 2 days without stock from 2021-11-21 (the last date without stock) to today.
- **SKU 146:** Don't show in this result because today it has stock again from today.

I hope to explain it well.

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem using next query:

```
select
    sku, 
    DATEDIFF( -- date diff in days between
        CURRENT_DATE,  -- current date
        MAX(if(quantity > 0, `date`, '')) -- last date with stock
    ) days_without_stock
from sku
group by sku
having days_without_stock > 0;
```

[MySQL group by fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=0717e6345712dab9e51f24538cc2d5ca&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a real g thing to do if you have a sql question to build the sql fiddle schema for any potential answerers.

Anyway, something like:

```
select 
a.sku,
datediff(current_date, date_last_stock) - 1 as days_wo_stock
from stock a
left join (
  select 
  sku, 
  max(date) date_last_stock
  
  from stock 
  
  where qty > 0
  
  group by 
  sku
 ) b on a.sku = b.sku

where a.date = current_date
and a.qty = 0
```

See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02e05a/7/0). Works on MySQL 5.6